# Catch axios requests in different files / functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, exception, axios, es6-promise

I use HTTP requests to get data for my Vue.js application. I have one file called *Api.js* with the base axios instance:

```
export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: apiURL,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `JWT ${store.state.token}`
    }
  })
}
```

than I have a file called *service.js*, which contains the functions for the different endpoints:

```
export default {
  status() {
    return Api().get('status/')
  }
}
```

In the *.vue* file I call the method like that.

```
created() {
  Service.status()
    .then(response => {
      // do something with the data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // show exception
    })
}
```

Some exceptions should be handled in *Api.js* (for example: 401), some other exceptions should be handled in *service.js* and others in the *.vue* file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I have created two small axios plugins to achieve this specific pattern easily.*

## [axios-middleware](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/)

> Simple axios HTTP middleware service to simplify hooking to HTTP requests made through Axios.

It uses axios interceptors as [mentioned by acdcjunior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49636062/1218980) but it abstracts the use of axios with a commonly known middleware pattern so your app doesn't need to know and deal with the interceptor syntax.

```
// import your API's axios instance
import http from './api';
import { Service } from 'axios-middleware';

// Create a new service instance
const service = new Service(http);

// We're good to go!
export default service;
```

You can then use this middleware service to register different middlewares anywhere in your app. A middleware can be as simple as an object or a reusable, easily testable class.

```
import i18n from './services/i18n';
import toast from './services/toast';
import service from './services/middleware';
import { ApiErrorMiddleware, OtherMiddleware } from './middlewares';


// Then register your middleware instances.
service.register([
    // Middleware class instance
    new ApiErrorMiddleware(i18n, toast),
    new OtherMiddleware(),
    // or a simple object
    {
        onRequest() {
            // handle the request
        },
        onResponseError(error) {
            // handle the response error
        }
    }
]);
```

Where the `ApiErrorMiddleware` would be a simple class with the sole responsibility of showing toast messages on error.

```
export default class ApiErrorMiddleware {
    /**
     * @param {VueI18n} i18n instance
     * @param {Object} toast message service
     */
    constructor(i18n, toast) {
        this.toast = toast;
        this.i18n = i18n;
    }

    /**
     * @param {Object} error
     */
    onResponseError(error = {}) {
        const { response } = error;
        let key = 'errors.default';

        if (response && this.i18n.te(`errors.${response.status}`)) {
            key = `errors.${response.status}`;
        } else if (error.message === 'Network Error') {
            key = 'errors.network-error';
        } else {
            // TODO log unhandled errors
        }
        this.toast.error(this.i18n.t(key));
    }
}
```

## [axios-resource](https://emileber.github.io/axios-resource/#/)

> Simple axios resource class to easily interact with a REST endpoint.

Define a resource class. Here, I added `onError` and `onFetchError` as examples for your use-case.

```
import Resource from 'axios-resource';

export default class UserResource extends Resource {
    static URL = 'user/{id}';

    // This calls `sync` in the background
    fetch() {
        return super.fetch.apply(this, arguments)
            .catch(err => this.onFetchError(err));
    }

    onFetchError(err) {
        // An error occurred while fetching this resource.
    }

    onError(err) {
        // An error occurred with this resource
    }

    // called for every actions (fetch, create, patch, delete)
    sync() {
        return super.sync.apply(this, arguments)
            .catch((err) => this.onError(err))
    }
}
```

Then, in `api.js`, create an instance.

```
import UserResource from './user';

const user = new UserResource();

// GET https://example.com/api/user/me
user.fetch('me')
    .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log('User data:', data);
    });
```

The error can be dealt with at every step.

1. in the `onFetchError` of this specific resource
2. in the `onError` of this resource
3. in a middleware for the app.

Answer (score 0):

You should add [**axios interceptors**](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors):

> ## Axios Interceptors
>
> You can intercept requests or responses before they are handled by
>   `then` or `catch`.
>
> ```js
> // Add a request interceptor
> axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
>     // Do something before request is sent
>     return config;
>   }, function (error) {
>     // Do something with request error
>     return Promise.reject(error);
>   });
>
> // Add a response interceptor
> axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
>     // Do something with response data
>     return response;
>   }, function (error) {
>     // Do something with response error
>     return Promise.reject(error);
>   });
> ```

Those can (should) be in your *Api.js*.