# How to separate AXIOS requests from a Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a very normal **Vuex store file** and here is the code:

```
//store.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';


Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loading: true,
    companyBasicInfo: [

    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    getCompanyBasicInfo: (state, res) => {
      state.companyBasicInfo.push(res);
    },
    changeLoadingStatue: (state, loading) => {
      state.loading = loading;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getCompanyBasicInfo: context => {
// HERE IS MY AXIOS REQUESTS
    }
  }
});
```

I am writing my axios request in **getCompanyBasicInfo()** actions and everything works perfectly.

### What I want to do

Separate my **AXIOS** requests in another file and just call them in my store.js file just to reduce my store.js file..

### What I have tried

I have tried to create file called **requests.js** and write this code in it:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default GET_COMPANY_DETAILS = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/companies/show/trade key egypt').then((res) => {
      context.commit('getCompanyBasicInfo', res.data);
      context.commit('changeLoadingStatue', false);
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }, 3000);
};
```

And then trying to import them in my store.js file

```
import requests from './requests';
```

### Problem

Whenever I try to write `requests.GET_COMPANY_DETAILS();` in my `getCompanyBasicInfo()` action I couldn't access the method in the `requests.js` file.

### ERROR I get

`Uncaught ReferenceError: GET_COMPANY_DETAILS is not defined` in console

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I've just written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49638616/1218980) with examples on [`axios-middleware`](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/) and [`axios-resource`](https://emileber.github.io/axios-resource/#/) which helps with that.

Comment: @Prashant i have edited my question

Comment: Why are you wrapping the axios call in a `setTimeout`?

Comment: @EmileBergeron problem is that  I couldn't access any variable from my file not only axios requests functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Export problem

Since you're using `export default GET_COMPANY_DETAILS`, when you import `requests`, it is the `GET_COMPANY_DETAILS` function.

So you could call `requests()` directly.

See the [MDN documentation on `export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) to see all the possibilities.

## How to export an API

That being said, the proper way to export an API would be:

```
// api.js
import axios from 'axios';

// create an axios instance with default options
const http = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/' });

export default {
    getCompanyDetails(tradeKey) {
        // then return the promise of the axios instance
        return http.get(`companies/show/${tradeKey}`)
            .catch(e => {
                // catch errors here if you want
                console.log(e);
            });
    },
    anotherEndpoint() {
        return http.get('other/endpoint');
    }
};
```

You can export a `default` API like I did, or even both named and default export.

```
export function getCompanyDetails(tradeKey){ /*...*/ }
export default { getCompanyDetails }
```

Then, in your store:

```
import api from './api';

// ...

actions: {
    getCompanyBasicInfo({ commit }, key) {
        // It's important to return the Promise in the action as well
        return api.getCompanyDetails(key).then(({ data }) => {
            commit('getCompanyBasicInfo', data);
            commit('changeLoadingStatue', false);
        });
    }
}
```

The store related code still needs to be within your actions.

## Push the isolation a step further

I've written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49638616/1218980) with examples on [axios-middleware](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/) and [axios-resource](https://emileber.github.io/axios-resource/#/) which helps create single responsibility modules.

You can handle errors in a middleware, while focusing the endpoint configuration within resource classes.

Comment: I get the same error which say: `Uncaught ReferenceError: GET_COMPANY_DETAILS is not defined`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time that was really helpful

Comment: @Dill are you sure Prashant answer is the one you want to accept? I've gone into a little mode details and it could be more useful for future visitors. (in addition to editing the formatting of your question)

Comment: actually both answers really helped me

Comment: @Dill yes but Prashant answer still have incorrect information, like the missing `return` in the action function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you structure your code according to suggested [application structure](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/structure.html) in Vuex documentation.

That will give you nice separation of concerns and make your store.js nice and lean.

Then, export the function instead of exporting it as default. In future, you may want to export multiple functions from `requests.js`.

E.g.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function getCompanyDetails() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/companies/show/trade key egypt').then((res) => {
      context.commit('getCompanyBasicInfo', res.data);
      context.commit('changeLoadingStatue', false);
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }, 3000);
};

export function someOtherApiMethod() {}
```

Then, instead of using `setTimeout` in `GET_COMPANY_DETAILS`, return the promise from Axios itself.

E.g.

```
 export function getCompanyDetails() {
    return axios
        .get('http://localhost:3000/companies/show/trade key egypt')
        .then(res => res.data)
};
```

Then, use the promise in your action

```
import { getCompanyDetails } from './requests';

actions: {
    getCompanyBasicInfo: context => {
        getCompanyDetails().then(() => {
            // commit your mutations
        });
    }
  }
```